# Theme without require.js, knockout.js, AngularJS

Tags: magento2, javascript, frontend, knockoutjs, requirejs

I'm evaluating a the moment Magento2 as a solution for our Shop and I looked into a lot of Shops based on Magento2 to test the frontend performance and to be honest, I'm shocked. Every Shop I saw needs ~5 sec. to just render the form in the checkout (all of these Shope are already in production and some are even huge brands.).

I don't want to rant about M2, because I think the basic concept is pretty good, except the frontend part :)

**Can someone recommend a basic theme without all of these javascript frameworks and maybe twig templates or does someone already has experience with removing all of these JS Frameworks from M2 and can share some thoughts?**

Answer (score 0):

I dont know if you still searching this kind of theme , if so I would suggest https://hyva.io/. I haven't used it yet but it really looks promising.